# What is the probability of when drawing 10 items from a set of 100 with replacement that you draw the same 5 items twice in the 10 draws?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If I am drawing 10 items from a set of 100, each item is unique i.e $X_1$ to $X_{100}$, what is the probability that in the 10 draws I draw 5 items exactly twice. A success for example would be $\lbrace X_1,X_1,X_2,X_2,X_3,X_3,X_4,X_4,X_5,X_5 \rbrace$. Order does not matter.

So far I am thinking its 1*$\frac{99}{100}*\frac{98}{100}*\frac{97}{100}*\frac{96}{100}*\frac{5}{100}*\frac{4}{100}*\frac{3}{100}*\frac{2}{100}*\frac{1}{100}$. As we need to draw 5 unique items and then we need to draw the five unique items again.

Comment: You could draw the same items in a different order, so should should have an answer several times your result.  Try it drawing $4$ times from a set of $3$

Comment: One of my other ideas was 1*$\frac{1}{100}$*$\frac{99}{100}$*$\frac{1}{100}$*$\frac{98}{100}$*$\frac{1}{100}$*$\frac{97}{100}$*$\frac{1}{100}$*$\frac{96}{100}$*$\frac{1}{100}$. I think this one accounts for the different order

Comment: Try it drawing $4$ times from a set of $3$: the true answer is $\frac{2}{9}$ while your first method would give $1\times \frac23\times\frac23 \times \frac13= \frac4{27}$.

Answer (score 1):

The five duplicates can be chosen ${100 \choose 5} = 75287520$ ways.  For each of these sets of $5$ there are $\frac{10!}{(2!)^5}$ equivalent rearrangements.

Thus there are $8537604768000$ ways to make ten selections of which there are exactly two repetitions from each of five categories (objects).

To get the *probability* divide this by the total number of ways you can choose 10 items without restriction:  $100^{10}$.

I get:  $p = 8.5376 \cdot 10^{-8}$.